# port forwarding is configured, netstat says port is open but cannot access the server (ping fails)

Tags: django, mongodb, networking, server, routes

I have a Django web server and mongodb server running at port 80 and 27017.

bindIP (Allowed IPs) are configured to allow any IPs ("*"/"0.0.0.0")

from `netstat -tuplen` I am seeing

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:27017           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      126        1280676    -                   
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      0          1319550    -
```

I know that the public IP is the IP for the router and port forwarding has to be configured.
Therefore, I opened the router setting and configure it so that connections to `:80` and `:27017` are redirected to the machine that runs the servers.

After this configuration, I confirmed that the ports are open using this web page (https://www.yougetsignal.com/tools/open-ports/)

However, when I ping the router IP address, it doesn't get any response,
navigation to the web server says it takes too long and site can't be reached
accessing the mongodb server fails with following msgs

```
xxx@xxx:~$ mongo --host 142.xxx.xxx.xxx
MongoDB shell version v4.4.5
connecting to: mongodb://142.xxx.xxx.xxx:27017/?compressors=disabled&gssapiServiceName=mongodb
Error: couldn't connect to server 142.xxx.xxx.xxx:27017, connection attempt failed: SocketException: Error connecting to 142.xxx.xxx.xxx:27017 :: caused by :: Connection timed out :
connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:374:17
@(connect):2:6
exception: connect failed
exiting with code 1
```

I ran `traceroute` command and this is what I am seeing

```
xxx@xxx:/etc/apt/sources.list.d$ traceroute 142.xxx.xxx.xxx
traceroute to 142.xxx.xxx.xxx (142.xxx.xxx.xxx), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  Roboeye (192.xxx.xxxx.xxx)  5.621 ms  9.267 ms  9.231 ms
 2  192.xxx.xxx.xxx (192.xxx.xxx.xxx)  10.854 ms  10.830 ms  11.086 ms
 3  199.xxx.xxx.xxx (199.xxx.xxx.xxx)  12.502 ms  12.475 ms  12.520 ms
 4  216.xxx.xxx.xxx (216.xxx.xxx.xxx)  12.625 ms  12.600 ms  12.579 ms
 5  64.xxx.xxx.xxx (64.xxx.xxx.xxx)  14.470 ms  14.449 ms  14.738 ms
 6  * vlnsm3-abc63-142-xxx-xxx-xxx.internet.abcdef.xx (142.xxx.xxx.xxx)  19.240 ms *
```

when I run `rounte -n`, I do see privet router IP from the list

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.2.1     0.0.0.0         UG    600    0        0 wlo1 <------ private rounter ip
25.0.0.0        0.0.0.0         255.0.0.0       U     0      0        0 ham0
169.xxx.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 wlo1
172.xx.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 docker0
192.xxx.2.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     600    0        0 wlo1
```

Is there anything else that I am supposed to configure?
If anyone can tell me what might be going wrong, it would be great

Comment: Is the router the default gateway for the servers?

Comment: @Joe when I run `route -n` I see an entry with Router Private IP for `wlo1`. I added what I see from `route -n` on the post

Comment: You've verified that you can reach the router externally, the next step would be to watch the network traffic at the server to see if the packets are recieved, and where the replies are sent.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about mongodb, but make sure the port forwarding redirect requests to the right ports.

Also, did you use the internal IP (192.168.x.x in general) in your router's settings ?

Comment: It is Django server and have `ALLOWED_HOSTS = ["*"]` 
Is there a way to check if port forwarding redirect requests to the right ports?

Comment: Yes, do (on your Django server) :
`nc -l 80`
**Without Django running**
Now, **outside** of your LAN, try :
`nc the.ip.ofyour.router 80`
And type anything. If you see it your terminal emulator on the server, port forwarding is correctly configured. If not, there is a problem.

Comment: Note : You may have to type `sudo nc -l -p 80` depending on your distro.